# Marshaling issue with char** while accessing a library function

Tags: c#, linux, gcc, mono

I'm porting an existing library/DLL writen in C++/VisualStudio to codeblocks/GCC. The DLL in Windows has been tested in C#, C, C++, Python, Delphi, Java, VB.NET, LabVIEW, etc and works fine and stable.
However, when porting it to Linux, I'm having issues while testing it from Mono/C#, while it's working fine from FreePascal and Python.

The root of the issue is a function that detects some devices and returns an integer with the number of devices detected, and a list of the paths (array of ASCII strings of chars) where the devices are located, through parameters:

```
int DetectDevices(char ** DevicePaths);
```

They way I'm copying the results in the library is:

```
i=0;
for (vector<string>::iterator it=lstDetected.begin(); it!=lstDetected.end(); ++it)
    strcpy(DevicePaths[i++], (*it).c_str());
```

In C#, I declare the external function using the following code:

```
[DllImport(LIBRARY_PATH)]
public static extern int DetectDevices([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] DevicePaths);
```

I would like to note, that I'm actually reserving some memory space in C# before calling the function and getting the value returned:

```
string[] DevicePaths = new string[50];
for (int i=0; i<DevicePaths.Length; i++)
    DevicePaths[i] = new string('\0', 255);
```

This is working fine in Windows/VisualStudio, but not in Linux/Mono.

Replacing LPStr with LPWStr and performing a debug, shows that the characters are supposedly arriving but the equivalent ASCII code received is 0 for all the characters in LPStr and 63 in LPWStr.

I'm thinking that this could be related to an issue related with character encoding, but I might be wrong.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be wrong here?
Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: what character set are you using for compilation (unicode or multi byte)?

Comment: `strcpy(DevicePaths[i++], (*it).c_str())` and where are you cheking if you are not exceed the array?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia sincerely, I've not set this up in codeblocks/GCC, so I presume it is being treated as ASCII

Comment: @Selvin Since I'm the one which is testing this, I can confirm that memory is not an issue. I don't think this is relevant. Take also into account that I've simplified that loop here, removing all non-related code.

Comment: Maybe a character enconding issue on GCC? How should I properly set the character encoding?

Comment: I bet that memory is an issue ... how you are *reserving some memory space in C#* ... `string[] DevicePaths = new string[x];` ? then where are you allocating memory where `strcpy` will copy the strings?

Comment: @I've just edited the question in order to show the way I reserve the memory. And I don't think this is an issue, since it works fine in Windows and also in Linux (Python and FreePascal)

Comment: *"This is working fine in Windows/VisualStudio, but not in Linux/Mono."* - You have to do better than this problem statement. Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And `String` is immutable in C#. I believe you have to use a `StringBuilder`. [c# how to marshal "string\[\]" site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+marshal+"string[]"+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @jww I think you have not read the full post. All the relevant parts of the code are there and I explain what I mean with "does not work". StringBuilder can't be used for arrays Marshaled. This is unsafe code being converted to a fixed object, this why it's important to use an inmutable, pre-set var and not a dynamic var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution to the Marshaling problem.

While in Windows (.NET framework) & Visual Studio, returning an C array of strings (array of char array) parameter through the following manner is allowed:

```
[DllImport(LIBRARY_PATH)]
public static extern int DetectDevices([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] DevicePaths);
```

for some reason this is not working in Linux / Mono and I had to use the following method:

```
public static extern int DetectDevices(IntPtr[] pDevicePaths);
```

and then, in the code retrieve each string using the following method:

```
const int VCOUNT = 50;
const int MAXSTRINGSIZE = 255;
string[] MyValues = new string[VCOUNT];

IntPtr[] ptr = new IntPtr[VCOUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < ptr.Length; i++) ptr[i] = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(MAXSTRINGSIZE);

int n = DetectDevices(ptr);
if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr[i]));
        MyValues[i] = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is a more C/C++ style, which adds complexity but makes sense.
So I believe that either Mono is not fully implemented or there is a bug somewhere.

In case anyone has a better solution, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LPTStr` which will convert the string to the platform’s default string encoding. For Mono this is `UTF-8`.

- `UnmanagedType.LPStr` => ansi
- `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` => unicode
- `UnmanagedType.LPTStr` => platform default

There are other `UnmanagedType` that could also help... `BStr` perhaps...?

If this does not help then consider using Custom Marshaling or Manual Marshaling.

The [documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) is pretty good.

Comment: I've tested all of the options above with no luck. LPWStr return the right character count, but all the character values are 63.
BStr creates an exception.
I have also checked this documentation, but I didn't find anything useful there for my particular issue.

Comment: @Carles - How about with `LPTStr`? What do you get?

Comment: Nothing, all is set to the initial values: 0. The only that gives me somthing is LPWStr, which results is the number of characters that I expect, but all of them set to 63 (which I think is the higher part of a multibyte or unicode char).